# Command Line File Diff & Merge via Anaconda's Spyder

Tags: python, shell, anaconda, git-merge, spyder

Does the Spyder IDE provide for file diff & merge configuration via the command line?  I haven't seen anything relevant in their documentation nor have I found a plugin that might provide this functionality.  No relevant options seem to be available by default:

```
~$ which spyder
//anaconda/envs/test_env/bin/spyder

~$ spyder --help
Usage: spyder [options] files

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --new-instance        Run a new instance of Spyder, even if the single
                        instance mode has been turned on (default)
  --defaults            Reset configuration settings to defaults
  --reset               Remove all configuration files!
  --optimize            Optimize Spyder bytecode (this may require
                        administrative privileges)
  -w WORKING_DIRECTORY, --workdir=WORKING_DIRECTORY
                        Default working directory
  --show-console        Do not hide parent console window (Windows)
  --multithread         Internal console is executed in another thread
                        (separate from main application thread)
  --profile             Profile mode (internal test, not related with Python
                        profiling)
  --window-title=WINDOW_TITLE
                        String to show in the main window title
  -p OPEN_PROJECT, --project=OPEN_PROJECT
                        Path that contains an Spyder project
```

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 3):

(*Spyder maintainer here*)

> Does the Spyder IDE provide for file diff & merge configuration via the command line?

No, it doesn't. There are other IDEs that provide it, e.g. VSCode and Atom, but in its graphical interface not through its command line options.

Comment: a diff tool within Spyder would be really awesome. Cough cough hint hint.  (I always end up just using some online diff interface because lazy)

Comment: This could come when we improve our Git support in Spyder 5.